# Distribute circles on sides of a curve

Tags: objects, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

Part of what I want to do for a project is to distribute circles on the sides of a curve similar to the photo below. It's a proprietary tool in Maya.
[image]

How can I do that in Blender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, all you would have to do here is duplicate the curve, and move the individual curve points along their normal a bit.

[image]
[image]

A simplified solution might look something like this:

[image]

1. First I resample the Bezier curve so that I get a curve with even subdivision.
2. Then I duplicate the curves.
3. The curve index helps me, together with a value for the offset, to create a target value for moving the duplicated curve points.
4. So that the object can be controlled however over the curve *Radius*, I scale the normals of the individual points not only with this *Offset*, but multiply additionally with the given *Radius*.
5. Finally, I instantiate objects at the points of the curves, but in alternating order, so that of the curves with even index every second point starting with $0$ is used, and of the curves with odd index every second point starting with $1$ is used.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>